# Using AWS to do product lookup by UPC to get the products ASIN

Tags: c#, amazon-advertising-api

I am tasked right now to figure out a way my company can do a product search by UPC so we can grab the ASIN (Amazon Serial Identification Number). I was hoping someone could lead me in the right direction into what Amazon API I could use to do this. I would think they would have some API that allows a product search.

Also I am looking to implement this in C#/.NET.

Thanks for the help!
-Lewis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html), more specifically the ItemLookup API with an IdType of UPC. There is sample C# [code available here](http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/2480).

Make sure you read the licensing terms of the API though, as they are quite restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library [Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising) you can install it easy with nuget. The library also support .NET Standard 2.0.

```
PM> Install-Package Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising
```

Example code:

```
var authentication = new AmazonAuthentication();
authentication.AccessKey = "accesskey";
authentication.SecretKey = "secretkey";

var wrapper = new AmazonWrapper(authentication, AmazonEndpoint.US);
//The Lord of the Rings
var result = wrapper.Lookup("978-0261102385");
```

Answer (score -3):

You simply paste your UPC in search bar of amazon and hit Go, you will get result, after that you have to match description of item with your given product description, matched one is your  right product, some time we finf more than one ASIN for a SKU

Regards,

Shahmeen